# create a xml file with namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, vb.net

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest identifier="D2L_1000000179" xmlns:d2l_2p0="http://desire2learn.com/xsd/d2lcp_v2p0" xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1">
  <resources>
    <resource identifier="res_question_library" type="webcontent" d2l_2p0:material_type="d2lquestionlibrary" d2l_2p0:link_target="" href="questiondb.xml" title="Question Library" />
    <resource identifier="res_quiz_1000000179" type="webcontent" d2l_2p0:material_type="d2lquiz" d2l_2p0:link_target="" href="quiz_d2l_1000000179.xml" title="Quiz to test D2L import" />
  </resources>
</manifest>
```

I want to create this xml file .
but when i am creating this using `Xelement or XmlElemenmt` i am getting this one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest identifier="D2L_1000000179" xmlns:d2l_2p0="http://desire2learn.com/xsd/d2lcp_v2p0" xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1">
  <resources>
    <resource identifier="res_question_library" type="webcontent" material_type="d2lquestionlibrary" link_target="" href="questiondb.xml" title="Question Library" />
    <resource identifier="res_quiz_1000000179" type="webcontent" material_type="d2lquiz" link_target="" href="quiz_d2l_1000000179.xml" title="Quiz to test D2L import" />
  </resources>
</manifest>
```

here `d2l_2p0:material_type` is coming like `material_type`.

some one help me to create this using .net framework.

code for this is here below

```
private void createMenifetData(string destPath, long listExam)
{
    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
    XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration = xDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "");
    XmlElement rootnode = xDoc.CreateElement("manifest");
    xDoc.InsertBefore(xmlDeclaration, xDoc.DocumentElement);
    rootnode.SetAttribute("identifier", "D2L_" + listExam.ToString());
    rootnode.SetAttribute("xmlns:d2l_2p0", "http://desire2learn.com/xsd/d2lcp_v2p0");
    rootnode.SetAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1");

    XmlElement resources = xDoc.CreateElement("resources");
    XmlElement resource = xDoc.CreateElement("resource");
    resource.SetAttribute("identifier", "res_question_library");
    resource.SetAttribute("type", "webcontent");
    resource.SetAttribute(@"d2l_2p0:material_type", "d2lquestionlibrary");
    resource.SetAttribute(@"d2l_2p0:link_target", "");
    resource.SetAttribute("href", "questiondb.xml");
    resource.SetAttribute("title", "Question Library");
    resources.AppendChild(resource);

    XmlElement resource1 = xDoc.CreateElement("resource");
    resource1.SetAttribute("identifier", "res_quiz_" + listExam);
    resource1.SetAttribute("type", "webcontent");
    resource1.SetAttribute(@"d2l_2p0:material_type", "d2lquiz");
    resource1.SetAttribute(@"d2l_2p0:link_target", "");
    resource1.SetAttribute("href", "quiz_d2l_" + listExam + ".xml");
    resource1.SetAttribute("title", "Quiz to test D2L import");
    resources.AppendChild(resource1);

    rootnode.AppendChild(resources);
    xDoc.AppendChild(rootnode);
    xDoc.Save(destPath + "\\imsmanifest.xml");}
```

Comment: Please show your code. Otherwise we can't fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you tagged this VB I'd just go the simplest route and use XML literals:

```
    Dim T = <manifest identifier="D2L_1000000179" xmlns:d2l_2p0="http://desire2learn.com/xsd/d2lcp_v2p0" xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1">
                <resources>
                    <resource identifier="res_question_library" type="webcontent" d2l_2p0:material_type="d2lquestionlibrary" d2l_2p0:link_target="" href="questiondb.xml" title="Question Library"/>
                    <resource identifier="res_quiz_1000000179" type="webcontent" d2l_2p0:material_type="d2lquiz" d2l_2p0:link_target="" href="quiz_d2l_1000000179.xml" title="Quiz to test D2L import"/>
                </resources>
            </manifest>
```

This kicks out:

```
<manifest identifier="D2L_1000000179" xmlns:d2l_2p0="http://desire2learn.com/xsd/d2lcp_v2p0" xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1">
  <resources>
    <resource identifier="res_question_library" type="webcontent" d2l_2p0:material_type="d2lquestionlibrary" d2l_2p0:link_target="" href="questiondb.xml" title="Question Library" />
    <resource identifier="res_quiz_1000000179" type="webcontent" d2l_2p0:material_type="d2lquiz" d2l_2p0:link_target="" href="quiz_d2l_1000000179.xml" title="Quiz to test D2L import" />
  </resources>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I've never understood why people tag it as both. I think I'll tag my next question as `html` or `assembler`!

Answer (score 1):

```
    XNamespace defaultNamespace = "http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1";

    const string NAMESPACE_URI = "http://desire2learn.com/xsd/d2lcp_v2p0";
    const string NAMESPACE_PREFIX = "d2l_2p0";

    XNamespace otherNamespace = NAMESPACE_URI;

    XElement root = new XElement(defaultNamespace + "manifest",
                        new XAttribute("identifier", "D2L_1000000179"),
                        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + NAMESPACE_PREFIX, NAMESPACE_URI),
                        new XElement(defaultNamespace + "resources",
                            new XElement(defaultNamespace + "resource",
                                new XAttribute("identifier", "res_question_library"),
                                new XAttribute("type", "webcontent"),
                                new XAttribute(otherNamespace + "material_type", "d2lquestionlibrary"),
                                new XAttribute(otherNamespace + "link_target", ""),
                                new XAttribute("href", "questiondb.xml"),
                                new XAttribute("title", "Question Library")),
                            new XElement(defaultNamespace + "resource",
                                new XAttribute("identifier", "res_quiz_1000000179"),
                                new XAttribute("type", "webcontent"),
                                new XAttribute(otherNamespace + "material_type", "d2lquiz"),
                                new XAttribute(otherNamespace + "link_target", ""),
                                new XAttribute("href", "quiz_d2l_1000000179.xml"),
                                new XAttribute("title", "Quiz to test D2L import"))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CreateAttribute method on XMLDocument to create an attribute with a namespace. Later append to the attributes collection of xmlelement that should have this attribute.

```
public XmlAttribute CreateAttribute(
string qualifiedName,
string namespaceURI
```

)